# Python, passing multiple parameters to different program via pipe

Tags: python, subprocess

I have two python scripts, progA.py and progB.py. I want to create a pipe to pass parameters from progA to progB and output the result from progB in progA.

The function that receives/reads the parameters within progB is getParameters()

```
def getParameters():
    global a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i
    sys.stdin.readline() # read a blank line (in input file from simviz1.py)
    a = float(sys.stdin.readline())
    b = float(sys.stdin.readline())
    c = float(sys.stdin.readline())
    d = sys.stdin.readline().strip()  # strip off '\n'
    e = float(sys.stdin.readline())
    f = float(sys.stdin.readline())
    g = float(sys.stdin.readline())
    h = float(sys.stdin.readline())
    i = float(sys.stdin.readline())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        print 'sys.argv[1]:', sys.argv[1]
        if sys.argv[1] == 'default':
            pass # no reading of input
        else:
           getParameters()
    else:
        getParameters()
    myloop()
```

When I create a pipe in progA like this (passing 'default' to progB uses predefined values for a-i)

```
import subprocess as sp
if __name__ == '__main__':
    echo = sp.Popen(['progB.py','default'],
                    stdin = sp.PIPE,
                    stdout = sp.PIPE,
                    shell = True)

myValue = echo.communicate()[0]
print myValue
```

I get the correct output printed within progA. I'm trying to pass modified values from progA to progB instead of the default ones, but for my life I can't figure out how. I think that I'm on the right path, but I'm stuck, and I'm looking for help.

Any hints, tips, or advice is greatly appreciated!!!!!

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you can pass a string argument to `echo.communicate()` that will be used as input. For example: `echo.communicate("\n1.0\n2.0\n....")`

Comment: Instead of running a subprocess; you could import the module. And instead of reading parameters from stdin; you could pass them as function parameters e.g., in `progA.py`: `import progB; result = progB.myloop(a,b,c,d,...)`

Comment: @ Markku
Son of a gun, that worked!!!
Thanks Markku!! You're the man!
this is what i used:

`echo = sp.Popen(['oscillator03.py',''],stdin = sp.PIPE,stdout=sp.PIPE,shell = True)`
    
`myValue = echo.communicate('\n1.0\n1.0\n1.0\ny1\n1.0\n1.0\n1.0\n10.0\n0.05\n')
print myValue[0]`